# Upload multiple images - NodeJS & Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have been able to set up a process to upload a single image at a time using NodeJS/Express/Amazon S3/ Multer. It works perfectly. I've been trying to change the code to allow users to upload more than one image at a time. So far I have been very unsuccessful. How would I change my code below to allow multiple images to be uploaded at once? Thanks!

```
aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: '*****************',
    accessKeyId: '******',
    region: 'us-east-2'
});

var s3 = new aws.S3();


var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'myfiles',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            var fileExtension = file.originalname.split(".")[1];
            var path = "uploads/" + req.user._id + Date.now() + "." + fileExtension;
            cb(null, path); 
        }
    })
});


router.post("/", upload.array('image', 1), function(req, res, next){

      var filepath = undefined;

    if(req.files[0]) {
        filepath = req.files[0].key;
    }......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have done the hard part, all what u have to do is to modify your html file input to make it accept multiple files like so

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

and change the number of files in the array to the maximum number of files you wan to upload

from

```
upload.array('image', 1)
```

to

```
upload.array('image', x)
```

where (x) is the maximum number of files per upload

**EDIT1 : update**

Here is kind of full example & to avoid "too large entity issue"

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var multer = require('multer');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');

var router = express.Router();
app.use("/", router);

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(cookieParser());
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000
});

// in case u want to c the requsted url
router.use(function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log('Request URL: ', req.originalUrl);
    next();
});

//the files will b uploaded to folder name uploads, html file input name is uploadedFile
app.post('/your/route', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) { 

            var storage = multer.diskStorage({
                destination: function(req, file, callback) {
                    callback(null, './uploads');
                },
                filename: function(req, file, callback) {
                    var fname = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
                    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
                }
            });
            var upload_photos = multer({
                storage: storage
            }).array('uploadedFile', 3);
            upload_photos(req, res, function(err) {
            // uploading files
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3

You can use this npm package for aws-s3 upload. I have used the same and saving files without any issue.