# Format issue while uploading Jpg file with NodeJS Multer module

Tags: node.js, post, jpeg, multer

I'm using Multer to upload jpg file from Postman to a node.js back-end.

I assume the "upload" goes well because the image is located at the right place with the right name and the right size after the POST request

Unfortunately, when I try to open the image file it doesn't open as a jpg image even though the extension is .jpg
I used checkFileType website and apparently, the file type becomes application/octet-stream after the upload.

I didn't specify any headers in the request.

[Here is my Postman setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g62N.png)

[Here is the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4qzI.png)

Here is the code in the Node API side

```
var localWorkLocation = '/Users/noste/CarFixer/Pictures/';

exports.createBinary = function (req, res) {
        var location = localWorkLocation + req.params.platenumber;
        var storageOptions = multer.diskStorage({
                        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
                            mkdirp(location, err => callback(err, location));
                            callback(null, location);
                        },
                        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                            //if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
                            //        return callback(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
                            //}
                            callback(null, file.originalname);
                        },
        });
        var upload = multer({storage : storageOptions}).single('picture');

        upload(req, res, function(err){
            console.log(req.file);
            if(err) {
                return res.end(err.message);
            }

            res.send(req.file);
        });
};
```

I've tried to upload a .txt file and it's still readable after upload.
Is there a place where I need to specify that I want to keep the jpg format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's the storage configuration u need .. change the naming according to your code

```
 var path = require('path');
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function(req, file, callback) {
                callback(null, './uploads');
            },

            filename: function(req, file, callback) {
                var fname = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);

                callback(null, fname);

            }
        });
```

And here's another answer for [multiple files upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339648/5924412)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It creates 2 files but one of them contain the picture.

Comment: @NicolasOste one file should b uploaded.. If it works with u plz accept the answer and vote up :D

Comment: In fact the problem is that : if I dont add a datetime in the filename, the first one that contains the picture correctly gets overwritted by the second one because they have the same name. I'm setting the filename to a specific id in order to retrievethe file afterward. Do you know how can I only store the first one ? Or to protect it from being overwritted ?

Comment: @NicolasOste u have to change the name by something that will not b repeated (or at least hardly repeated) even though u can come over this issue by a simple checking function .. so add datetime to the file name to prevent the overwrite